# Can't build a game on Web Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player, unity-webgl

My 2D game works well on Android and iOS. If I export it as WebGL build and open it on the browser, the browser is blocked. If I export it as a Web Player build, the build fails with the following errors in the console:

- `newpos < pos+kCompressAlign`
- `AlignBytesCompress(byteStart) == byteStar`

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages? Can you describe them? Can you describe your game (technically)? You've not given much information that would help someone understand the problem.

Comment: I get the following errors on console: newpos < pos+kCompressAlign  and AlignBytesCompress(byteStart) == byteStar

Comment: That's not an error message; that's a line of code. Can you edit your question to include a clear description of what you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, the game is simple: the user have to catch an animated mascot which is moving in the stage and I have multiple levels. I get the errors I mentioned in the previous comment after building on unity web player , I get them on console colored with red and the web player doesn't work

Comment: Those look like failed asserts. Unity's convention when an assert fails is the log the check that failed. Unfortunately, I don't recognize those particular messages. You might check the documentation to see if you have any large files or unusual texture sizes that are problematic, given the assert seems to be compression-related.